# Regex : capture 3 groups in a string "elem1/elem2@attr"

Tags: regex

Here's a simple job for regex.
I'm working on strings built on this model: `elem1/elem2@attr` (made up of word characters, and `/` and `@` used as separators).

I'm trying to capture the 3 parts : `elem1/`, `elem2`, `@attr`, knowing that a valid string can omit any of the 3 parts (but the separator order must be respected).

I've come up with this RegEx:

```
^(\w+\/)?(\w+)?(@\w+?)$
```

but it works only if the last part, `@attr`, is present.
I need a solution that also matches these strings : `elem1/`, `elem2`, `elem1/elem2`.

Any idea?

Comment: Regex doesn't require you to escape the forward slash.  Of course, your programming environment may require that, but this is a question about regex, not perl/php/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should be `^(\w+\/)?(\w+)?(@\w+)?$`

Answer (score 2):

you lost `?` =)
use regex:

```
^(\w+\/)?(\w+)?(@\w+?)?$
```

Comment: Damned! I'm sure I tried this in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but for some reason it didn't work. I can see it does now. (In fact, iWerner's answer is the right one...).

Comment: actually equivalent, i finished origin regex but not analyse it

Comment: +1 Yes, it's absolutely equivalent but the extra `?` is useless. Thank you anyway.